# Is it possible to use both email and phone verification in android using firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
private void verifyphone(final String phone)
{

    final String ph=phone;
    pDialog=new Dialog(this);
    pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.phoneverification);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pcode=pDialog.findViewById(R.id.pcodebtn);
    vcode=pDialog.findViewById(R.id.vcode);
    pstatus=pDialog.findViewById(R.id.pstatus);
    pDialog.show();

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phone, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, this, new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                pc=phoneAuthCredential;
                continueemail();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                // ...
                Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Invalid Phone number.Reenter correct phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                wrongnumber=true;
                Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // ...
                Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "SMS Quota exceeded.This is an internal error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Verification Code sent to the phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pstatus.setText("Verification Code has been sent to "+ph+".Please check phone and enter code to continue.");
            pvercode=s;
            mtoken=forceResendingToken;
        }
    });
    pcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(vcode.getText().toString())) {
                vcode.setError("Verification Code cannot empty");
            } else if (vcode.getText().toString().length() != 6) {
                vcode.setError("Verification code format is wrong");
            }
            else
                {
                    if(PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(pvercode,vcode.getText().toString())!=null)
                    {
                        pverified=true;
                        continueemail();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pverified=false;
                        pstatus.setText("Verification was unsuccessful.You entered wrong code!");
                        vcode.setError("Wrong Verification code was entered.");
                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Registration Failed,Pverified="+pverified, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
        }
    });

    if(wrongnumber)
    {
        pverified=false;
    }
    if(pverified) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

public void continueemail()
{
    pDialog.dismiss();
    mauth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(rmail.getText().toString(), rpass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
                user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "We have sent you an email verification.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Registration sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myDialog.dismiss();

            }
            else
            {
                rmail.setError("Enter a correct mailID we will be sending a verification mail.");
                Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "Wrong EmailID"+rmail.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am able to complete phone authentication. But it always says email ID is not valid(i.e task.issuccessful()method is returning false always).I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Please help me out. Is it possible to authenticate both phone and email verification. Do I need to sign-out or something before I try to verify email after I verified phone number?

Comment: Have you enabled email/password sign in inside the Firebase console under the Auth section?

Comment: @DavidVelasquez Yes I have enabled.I used Firebase assistant to make sure the configuration is right.

Comment: Ok good. If you can post the log output you are receiving when the `onComplete()` method is called, that would help. Also, are you testing with random strings for the email? I believe Firebase does some validations on the email such as it must have an "@" character and must be a specific length  (forgot the exact length). The logs should provide a clue to the issue.

Comment: @DavidVelasquez OK I can send .But does phone authentication run on emulator for real time numbers.I tried for real numbers and it crashes in emulator but doesn't in phone.

Comment: According to the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), you cannot use an emulator for phone authentication. "Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator."

Comment: @DavidVelasquez Then how can I send the logcat for oncomplete.The app crashes crashes even before it reaches there.

Comment: You should post the log stack trace right when it crashed, so I can see what caused the crash.

Comment: @DavidVelasquez   well,trying to fix the error,i changed the code so much that the above code is changed a lot.I have asked another question on this.Kindly answer that https://stackoverflow.com/q/51636733/6877706

Comment: @DavidVelasquez Please don't mind.Also I am facing lot of other issues other than this.